# How to fetch Address book person's online/off-line status through objective c on MAC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, abaddressbook

I need  to fetch 'Address book person's online/off-line status' through objective C on Mac.

I need 'iChat service' whatever Address book has used to fetch online status of a Person.
Can anyone help me how can I get this though code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have edited the requirement. I have tried Address-book framework Functions. But didn't get any property of a person(ABPerson) for getting online/offline status.

Comment: Online status is not in the address book.  It's part of iChat and I don't think there's an API for it.

Comment: Can anybody tell y there are down votes for this question. Its really a relevant question. If you people haven't work through iChat service as Apple provides its own framework don't down-vote it.

Comment: @BlackFrog: Got the status: through NSNumber *statusKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[info objectForKey:k__kIMPersonStatusKey] integerValue]];

Comment: @BlackFrog : Can you vote for this question for reopening because its valid question and i got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`InstantMessage.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/InstantMessageProgGuide/Articles/UsingiChatServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004931-SW2) to find the status of the current user's buddies.

Specifically, it sounds like you want to call `-[IMService screenNamesForPerson:]` and pass the ABPerson you want to find the status of, then call `-[IMService infoForScreenName:]` on each returned name.

Inspect the returned dictionary's `IMPersonStatusKey` value to check the status manually, or call `+[IMService imageNameForStatus:]` on the value to get the name of an image you can display to indicate the status (the red or green "bubble" used in Mail.app, Contacts.app, and Calendar.app).

Comment: Hey @jatoben: got the person's offline /online status with NSNumber *statusKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[info objectForKey:k__kIMPersonStatusKey] integerValue]];

Thanks

Comment: Can you vote for this question for reopening because its valid question and i got the answer.